# Putting placeholder attribute on file type input field

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to put a placeholder for input field which are `file` type?

I already tried jquery watermark plugin and it doesn't work.

Comment: There shouldn't be a reason to put a placeholder on a file input. It accepts a file. I can't think of a situation where would need any hint about how to format the text they are typing into it or an example or anything else that placeholder is designed for. What is your use case? (Hopefully it isn't "to avoid using a `<label>`" since `placeholder` is very explicitly not a substitute for that element).

Comment: I simply want to show the default value if they didn't upload any.

Comment: No. As a next best, you could place a `<div>` above the file that displays a fallback text (or image), listening to the value of the `<input>` field and removing the fallback whenever the `<input>` is not empty.

Comment: No File Chosen is there by default.
Ideally you should not need any placeholder for it.

Comment: There isn't actually any chosen file by default. It is just that if the user didn't provided any file, the system will simply use the default one.

Comment: Then you don't have to do anything on client side.

Have Div or Label on your page that indicates whether the user has selected any file or not.

Comment: @Quentin: Here is a situation that a placeholder would come in handy. In a WordPress custom-post plugin, I have the usual form for uploading a file. Once the user selects the file and updates the post, the file is uploaded and the edit-page is refreshed (PHP) in light of the new data. In this case there already _is_ a file selected, but the `input` element misleadingly says `No file selected`. It wouldn't look so stupid if it could show the URL of the uploaded file instead of a block-headed, Procrustean saying.

Comment: @JohnK — That sounds like something more appropriately handled with a link to the currently uploaded file and a file input `<label>`ed "Replace foo.jpeg with a new file".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Placeholder attribute should not be used for `<input type="file">`. Placeholders are used to give a hint about the input. And as file input is itself a browse button, it is clearly seen that it is for choosing a file. And if there's no file chosen it shows "no file chosen" next to the button.

**Because**:

1. In some browsers it just shows up as a button.
2. It already have default text which can not be changed.
3. Each browser renders it in own way.
4. IE will not support placeholder text.