# How to apply watermark in file upload control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Putting placeholder attribute on file type input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685617/putting-placeholder-attribute-on-file-type-input-field)

[image]

i want to show something like this..

I have one file-upload control and need to show some value in default file-upload control text box. how it is possible.

Comment: Are you asking for the `placeholder` attribute? Please be more specific what you want, what you have tried and what does not work.

Comment: @Bergi yes i ma sking about placholder but its not working for me..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx

because it works for sure with textbox but i have not tried with file upload control.