# Symfony2 - add a placeholder to the file upload

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a form builder object in my Symfony2 project, where I am creating a file input:

```
$builder->add('presentation', 'file', array( 'required'  => false ));
```

Now, I would like to ad a placeholder in the input to show which files are accepted.

I tried:

```
$builder->add('presentation', 'file', array( 'required'  => false, 'placeholder': 'pdf' ));
```

But this is not possible, an error is genereted.

Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: why not use a label to add that information?

Comment: Do you have an example @Simon?

Comment: $builder->add('presentation', 'file', array('label' => 'Presentation to upload. Allowed filetypes are .ppt, .pptx, .pdf'))

Comment: Does not work, nothing happens when putting this label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without you telling us which error you received, it's safe to assume that the Symfony Form API does not allow placeholders to be put on file fields. Some browsers do not support placeholders and some will only render a button for input type `file`.

I tested for giggles in Firefox and Chrome, neither one will render the placeholder for the file field.

You should find another way to convey the information, perhaps in your template file you could add some help text around the form element.

**Additional Information about Placeholders and File Fields**

[Putting placeholder attribute on file type input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685617/putting-placeholder-attribute-on-file-type-input-field)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to find andother solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $builder->add('presentation', 'file', 
array( 'required'  => false, 'attr'  => array('placeholder'=> 'pdf') ));
```

Comment: Thank you cb0, but nothing happens the paraéeter is not shown.