# How can we set default text like Watermark text for input element of type file

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I used a function in javascript as given below and my Html tag looks like

input id="TestId" type="text"

JavaScript:

```
$('#TestId').blur(function(){
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).val('Please enter').addClass('Watermark');
    }
}).focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Please enter') {
        $(this).val('').removeClass('Watermark');
    }
}).val('Please enter').addClass('Watermark');
```

I works as expected if the type of Html element is text, its not working if type of element is file. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a hidden file input and a placeholder element to recreate the desired effect. I have made a quick example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WAtuj/

Take a look at how you may trigger the file change event:

```
$("span").click(function () {
    $("input:file").trigger("click");
});
$("input:file").change(function () {
    var fileName = $(this).val();
    $("span").text(fileName);
});
```

A more detailed and complex solution can be found here: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/12/10/how-to-create-a-custom-file-input-with-jquery-css3-and-php/

Also an appropriate solution would be just to wrap your input field with a `span` element and try to create a dead simple placeholder label using `:after` and `:before` pseudoclasses

Answer (score 2):

For setting watermark You should use placeholder attribute:

```
<input type=text placeholder="WaterMark">
```

You cannot set watermark for files

Comment: I was just writing that, but to also add that for a "file" input type you can't (and shouldn't) use a placeholder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685617/putting-placeholder-attribute-on-file-type-input-field

Comment: I would like to know, is it possible to add warkmark/default text for an html element of type file.

Comment: You can do it manualy, by adding a div over the file element using z-index css property