# Placeholder not displaying text for twitter bootstrap file upload

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, image-uploading

I am working on a form using twitter bootstrap Version 2.3.2, the form does not have any labels and each input field is using placeholder. All input fields on the form are displaying placeholder text except file upload.

I have tried adding `<input class="input-xxlarge" type="file" name="service_guide"
                 placeholder="Upload image"/>` but it does not seem to work.

Here is the HTML for fileupload

```
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
    <div class="input-append">
        <div class="uneditable-input span3">
            <i class="icon-file fileupload-exists"></i>
            <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
        </div>
    <span class="btn btn-file">
      <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
      <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
      <input class="input-xxlarge" type="file" name="service_guide"
             placeholder="Upload image"/>
    </span>
        <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what my form looks like
[image]

I will really appreciate any help here.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685617/putting-placeholder-attribute-on-file-type-input-field

Comment: Thanks Dan for sharing the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-input-element), `placeholder` attribute is valid for *<input>* only
when `type` is `text`, `search`, `url`, `tel`, `e-mail`, `password`, or `number`.

So, you better not use `placeholder` attribute for *<input type="file">*